# Customise a FastAPI response if query = null

Tags: python, json, postgresql, get, fastapi

I have a table set-up in Postgres that contains some user information. I am trying to work out how to query that table with a user ID, and return a custom response if the user ID does not appear in the table.

I am using the following table and schema to store the data:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))
```

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    phone: int
    status: int = 1
```

Following a tutorial, I can successfully query the table to return the object if found, and raise an exception if not...

```
@router.get("/{id}", response_model=schemas.UserResponse)
def get_user(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == id).first()
    print(user) # checking output
    
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, 
            detail=f"User with ID {id} not found.")

    return user
```

This partially works, in that it returns the correct user response model if the user is found. However, in the case that a user is not found in the table, I want to be able to return an object where the status variable = 0. I assume that will be in place of the HTTPException, but I'm not too sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer in the FastAPI documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/). The below seemed to work for me.

```
@router.get("/{id}", response_model=schemas.UserResponse)
def get_user(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == id).first()
    print(user) # checking output
    
    if not user:
        return JSONResponse(content = {'status' : '0'}, status_code=400)

    return user
```